# Redirect users after login Joomla 4

Tags: php, joomla

In Joomla 4, I want to send a link to my users so they open a specific webpage after logging in:

For example:

https://www.example.com/component/thiscomp/this/8?dominio=whatever&evento_id=99

As you may see above, the URL has 2 parts:

- the fixed part -> https://www.example.com/component/thiscomp/this/8
- and the variable part -> ?dominio=whatever&evento_id=99

So, is there a way to pass a query like this one to the login URL?

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0):

If you create a menu entry of type Users / Login FORM, you will see a tab called Options. Within there, you can specify a redirect to another existing menu entry, or to a free format URL.